# How to derive the existence of (a+b+c) in a set containing those elements

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

I am looking to derive the existence of quantity (a+b+c) given that so far I only have the group axioms and knowledge of the sum of two quantities from the Associative Law: a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c.

Assuming one wants to be utterly rigorous is it sufficient to just say that the RHS of the Assoc Law  is logically equivalent to (a + b + c) under all circumstances?

ie (a + b + c) = (a + b) + c

providing the sum is carried out in order from left to right.

My claim would be that it is not sufficient to say

a + (b + c) = (a + b + c) but

(a + b) + c = (a + b + c) and there is simply no other interpretation.

Comment: If $a,b,c $ are in the group $ G$, then by closure of $+$ (group axiom) it follows that $a+b+c$ is in $G$, thus $a+b+c$ exists. The associative law assumes $a,b,c\in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$, we define $a+b+c$ to be this value.

So its existence is guaranteed by the definition of addition in your group.

Comment: Thanks.  When you say 'we define' do you mean we have deduced the existence of (a+b+c) or we just assume it?  Also do you agree with my claim that we cannot deduce the existence of (c+b+a) since we have not yet encountered the axiom of commutativity.  i have added the label real-analysis to this question.

Comment: We deduce it from the definition of the binary product: if $a,b,c$ are in our group, then so is $a+b$ and then so is $(a+b)+c$.  Existence of $c+a+b$ established in the exact same way.

Comment: Can the existence of c+a+b be proven from what we know above without invoking the commutativity axiom?

Comment: $c+a$ exists and is an element in the group. So $(c+a)+b$ exists. That is $c+a+b$ by definition. I think you are thinking too hard about this -- you can perform the binary operation on any two things in the group. Don't ask me how to prove $b+a+c$ exists, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Many thanks - I have reposted and been clearer that I am interested in putting this on an ultimately rigorous basis as per analysis and reference to axioms etc.